# Understanding Memory Issues in CNNs: Investigating the Linear Layer Shape "in_features=32*7*"

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Sequential(

    nn.Conv2d(3,32,(3, 3)),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
    nn.Conv2d(32,32,(3, 3)),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
    nn.Flatten(),

    nn.Linear(in_features=32*7*7, out_features=100),
    nn.ReLU(),


    nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=5),
    nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)


print(model)
```

In this CNN code, I would like to understand how the Linear layer got the shape ***"in_features=32*7*7"***. When I run this code, my CPU crashes due to lack of memory.[Is it based on this equation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUmN3.png)

Comment: i mean the 32*7*7

Comment: "On the first linear layer, how did it arrive at the number 32*7*7? I Understand 32 from the last `out_channels` of the last 2D convolutional layer, but where did the 7*7 come from?". And my images in the dataset is in shape of 150*150*3